# filtering subforms in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I keep getting run-time error 2465 on line 4 (Me.ConstructQuery). I have a form with a tab control embedded into it; every tab will contain a sub-form. I want to be able to query each sub-form from multiple combo Boxes within each tab.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub cboLastName_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ConstructQuery
End Sub

Function ConstructQuery()
    Dim sFilter As String

    If Nz(Me.qryHardware.Form.cboUserID, "") <> "" Then
        sFilter = "UserID=" & Me.qryHardware.Form.cboUserID
    End If

    If Nz(Me.qryHardware.Form.cboLastName, "") <> "" Then
        sFilter = "LastName=" & Me.qryHardware.Form.cboLastName
    End If

    Me.qryHardware.Form.Filter = sFilter
    Me.qryHardware.Form.FilterOn = True


End Function

Private Sub cboBranch_Change()
    Dim strSQL As String

'populate userID comboBox
Me.cboUserID.ColumnCount = 2
Me.cboUserID.ColumnWidths = "0, 2cm"
strSQL = "SELECT ID, UserID  FROM Users WHERE BranchID=" &    Me.cboBranch.Value
Me.cboUserID.RowSource = strSQL

'populate last name comboBox
Me.cboLastName.ColumnCount = 1
Me.cboLastName.ColumnWidths = "2cm"
strSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Users WHERE BranchID=" & Me.cboBranch.Value
Me.cboLastName.RowSource = strSQL

'poplulate first name comboBox
Me.cboFirstName.ColumnCount = 2
Me.cboFirstName.ColumnWidths = "0, 2cm"
strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName FROM Users WHERE BranchID=" & Me.cboBranch.Value
Me.cboFirstName.RowSource = strSQL

'populate account Status comboBox
Me.cboAccountStatus.ColumnCount = 2
Me.cboAccountStatus.ColumnWidths = "0, 2cm"
strSQL = "SELECT ID, AccountStatus FROM Users WHERE BranchID=" & Me.cboBranch.Value
Me.cboAccountStatus.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Once again, the reported line throwing the exception is 
Me.ConstructQuery

Any advice or suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just contstructquery should do for that line.

Comment: Can you step through the code in debug mode and see where the line fails?  It's returning line 4 because that's the line that is calling the ConstructQuery method.  However, if you step through the code you might find the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Call it straight:

```
Public Sub cboLastName_AfterUpdate()
    ConstructQuery
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me past that line, however, getting error on following line,If Nz(Me.qryHardware.Form.cboUserID, "") <> ""

Comment: Try reducing it to: `Nz(Me!cboUserID.Value) <> ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that fixed it! I also had to enclose the string value within ' ' in order for it to properly search the sub-form.